# SqlAlchemy: Retrieve count from a SELECT COUNT(1) WHERE - style query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I cannot figure out how to retrieve the count from what appears to be a very simple Query. My code looks like this:

```
mod_count_query = db_session.query(func.count(User)).\
        filter(User.id == user_id).\
        filter(User.modification_date > time_start).filter(User.modification_date < time_end)
```

When I introspect the SQL it generates internally, it looks pretty reasonable:

```
SELECT count(:param_1) AS count_1 FROM user WHERE user.id = :user_id_1 AND user.modification_date > :date_1 AND user.modification_date < :date_2)
```

However, try as I might, I cannot figure out how to coax a number out of the `mod_count_query` object. Doing `mod_count_query.first()` or `mod_count_query.all()` results in:

```
{AttributeError}type object 'User' has no attribute 'translate'
```

I am able to move forward with [this workaround](https://gist.github.com/hest/8798884), but it seems I should be able to get this info off of the query object. What am I missing?

Comment: You should be doing `func.count(1)` if you want `SELECT COUNT(1)`.

Comment: Thanks univero. Then, how would I tell which table to do this on?

Comment: That's automatic. SQLAlchemy infers from the fact that your filters are on `User.id` and `User.modification_date`. If you want to make it explicit, you can do `.select_from(User)`.